# Vim: E682 Invalid search pattern or delimiter

Tags: vim

I am getting this error with some vim script file in .vim folder:

```
Error detected while processing /home/rafid/.vim/python.vim:
line 116
```

Line 116 contains this code:

```
vim:syntax = vim
```

Any body has in idea what the problem is?

Also, what is this statement supposed to do? I tried to search but couldn't because it is a composite statement.

**EDIT:** This is where I got the code from:

https://dev.launchpad.net/UltimateVimPythonSetup

Please see the end of the page.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was a typo in the question. It is written correctly in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aren't modelines supposed to be placed within comments?

This works for me: `" vim:syntax=vim`.

Notice the space between `"` and the start of the statement.

It seems to work with or without a space between the `vim:` and the options part. So both `" vim:syntax=vim` and `" vim: syntax=vim` are valid.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try fixing the typo?

vim:synatx = vim -> vim:syntax = vim

Sean

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was a typo in the question. It is written correctly in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a modeline? Then you need to redistribute spaces:

```
vim: syntax=vim
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and now I get the error: "E28 No such highlight group name: =vim"